# Performance of SASHELP views versus SQL dictionary tables

Tags: performance, sas

Why does it take longer for SAS to create a dataset from a data step view using, for example, `sashelp.vcolumn` versus the equivalent SQL table `dictionary.columns`?

I did a test using `fullstimer` and it seems to confirm my suspicion of performance differences.

```sql
option fullstimer;

data test1;
    set sashelp.vcolumn;
    where libname = 'SASHELP' and
        memname = 'CLASS' and
        memtype = 'DATA';
run;

proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select *
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = 'SASHELP' and
        memname = 'CLASS' and
        memtype = 'DATA';
quit;
```

An excerpt from the log:

```
NOTE: There were 5 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VCOLUMN.
      WHERE (libname='SASHELP') and (memname='CLASS') and (memtype='DATA');
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST1 has 5 observations and 18 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.67 seconds
      user cpu time       0.23 seconds
      system cpu time     0.23 seconds
      memory              3820.75k
      OS Memory           24300.00k
      Timestamp           04/13/2015 09:42:21 AM
      Step Count                        5  Switch Count  0


NOTE: Table WORK.TEST2 created, with 5 rows and 18 columns.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      user cpu time       0.01 seconds
      system cpu time     0.00 seconds
      memory              3267.46k
      OS Memory           24300.00k
      Timestamp           04/13/2015 09:42:21 AM
      Step Count                        6  Switch Count  0
```

The memory used is a little higher for SASHELP but the difference isn't huge. Note the time--it's *22 times* longer using SASHELP than with the SQL dictionary. Surely it can't just be due to the relatively small difference in memory usage.

At @Salva's suggestion, I resubmitted the code in a new SAS session, this time running the SQL step before the data step. The memory and time differences are even more pronounced:

```
                | sql       | sashelp
----------------+-----------+-----------
real time       | 0.28 sec  | 1.84 sec
user cpu time   | 0.00 sec  | 0.25 sec
system cpu time | 0.00 sec  | 0.24 sec
memory          | 3164.78k  | 4139.53k
OS Memory       | 10456.00k | 13292.00k
Step Count      | 1         | 2
Switch Count    | 0         | 0
```

Comment: Can you close your SAS session, reopen your SAS file, change the order of execution (PROC SQL first, then data step program) and post the results.  (I do not know the answer, but it will be interesting to see).

Comment: @Salva: Edited. Thanks for the suggestion. The results are indeed interesting.

Comment: Nice find.  Going to test this out myself as I've noticed that once you have a large number of tables/columns (tens of thousands) within your defined libnames, the performance of sashelp tends to drop.  Might try progressively adding them and timing them to see if the performance of dictionary is affected in any way.  Perhaps the dictionary approach is 'smarter' and limits its investigations to just those files it knows it needs to read...

Comment: I think there is some extra overhead with defining the views - it goes away mostly after the first run.

Comment: Interestingly enough, SAS's page claims the overhead going away is not the case: the dictionary tables are re-constructed from a "discovery process" every single query.

Comment: @andrey_sz That edit was entirely superfluous (and introduces a `proc sql` option that I wasn't using) so I've rolled it back. No idea how that edit got approved. Please avoid making edits like that in the future.

Comment: @AlexA. I agree that some of the edit was unnecessary (although still an improvement IMO).  However, the `noprint` option should actually be included if you are doing benchmarking, so I would have let the edit stand.  `noprint` will suppress displaying output to any active output destinations.  Displaying output is slow.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Everyone has their own code formatting preferences. It's not unreadable as-is. Also since this is a `create table`, no output would be generated anyway, regardless of `noprint`.

Comment: @AlexA. Actually, that's not necessarily true.  Earlier versions of SAS 9 definitely still ran the output code even if it wasn't displayed (someone that worked for SAS told me this).  I don't know if it's been fixed by then or not, but I know a lot of people that always include the `noprint` option for this reason.

Comment: @RobertPenridge That's good to know, but part of my objection to the edit adding that option is that the log output and benchmark times I included in the question did not use that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some (if not all) of this is the difference in overhead between SQL and Data Step.  For example:

```
proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select *
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = 'SASHELP' and
        memname = 'CLASS' and
        memtype = 'DATA';
quit;
```

Also very fast.

The SAS [page about Dictionary Tables](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001385596.htm) gives some information that is likely the main explanation.

> When querying a DICTIONARY table, SAS launches a discovery process
>   that gathers information that is pertinent to that table. Depending on
>   the DICTIONARY table that is being queried, this discovery process can
>   search libraries, open tables, and execute views. Unlike other SAS
>   procedures and the DATA step, PROC SQL can mitigate this process by
>   optimizing the query before the discovery process is launched.
>   Therefore, although it is possible to access DICTIONARY table
>   information with SAS procedures or the DATA step by using the SASHELP
>   views, it is often more efficient to use PROC SQL instead.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I tried looking for some information on how SAS constructs the SASHELP views for comparison but I came up short. If you happen across it at some point, I'd love if you could add it to your answer. But in the meantime, +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using the sashelp views is slower than using proc datasets. This is more so if you have a lot of libraries assigned, especially external ones:

```
10   proc datasets lib=sashelp noprint;
11     contents data=class out=work.test2;
12   quit;

NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST2 has 5 observations and 40 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE DATASETS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      user cpu time       0.00 seconds
      system cpu time     0.01 seconds
      memory              635.12k
      OS Memory           9404.00k
      Timestamp           14.04.2015 kl 10.22
```