# Detecting the latest modified date in a folder using SAS

Tags: sas

I am writing a program that needs to run every day. In a specific section of the program, all datasets in a specific library will be appended into one dataset in another library.

My plan is to scan the first library to retrieve the latest modified time and then compare this to the last modified time of the appended dataset in the second library. The script will only be executed if the last modified date in the first library is greater than that in the second library.

I have found a way to do this for a specific dataset using the PROC DATASET command, but since I have more than 200 individual datasets in my first library, I'm trying to find a more efficient solution.

I also found the following solution that I can't seem to get right (Keeps on saying that the directory can't be found on this machine, even though I'm using the exact same path for a LIBNAM assignment):

```
data _null_;
 infile 'dir \\path\to\my\folder\/o-d /b' pipe obs=1;
 input ;
 call symputx('last',_infile_);
run;
```

I am using a Windows system by the way.

Comment: I have not used pipe in infile statement before. What does this code produce:`filename d pipe "dir \\path\to\my\folder\/o-d /b";data _null_;infile d;input;put _infile_;run;`

Comment: @StigEide this also results in the error: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Does the path contain space? What if you start with the highest level (`\\path\to`) does that work?

Comment: @StigEide my file route does contain one space. If I change the above statement to this : 'dir "\\path\to\my\folder\"/o-d /b' it does find the folder. The problem was however solved by the answer below. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SAS` [dictionary](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002300185.htm) tables to find out the `last modified date` of the tables residing in a certain library.

```
    proc sql;
    create table dataset_1 as select libname,memname, modate 
from dictionary.tables where libname="your_library";
    quit;
```

Comment: this looks like a perfect solution in theory. When I run it however, it does not return any Observations. I tried it with various of my LIBNAMEs.

Comment: Probably you are missing to use upcase , as Memname and libname are always in caps

Comment: proc sql;
select libname,memname, modate 
from dictionary.tables where libname="SASHELP";
quit;

Comment: The UPCASE suggestion solved my problem Thanks @NEOMen

Comment: You said that you already had a solution using `proc datasets`, but you wanted a more efficient solution. See [this tread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610861/performance-of-sashelp-views-versus-sql-dictionary-tables) for a discussion about the efficience of the various methods